# How to classify English words according to topics with python?

Tags: python

How to classify English words according to topics with python? Such as  THE COUNTRY AND GOVERNMENT:  regime, politically, politician, official, democracy......besides, there are other topics: education/family/economy/subjects and so on.

I want to sort out *The Economist* magazine vocabularies and classify these **according to frequency and topic.** 
At present, I have completed the words frequency statistics, the next step is how to classify these words automatically with python?

Comment: try studying the  function map(),  it can help you

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called ["Topic Modelling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model). There are numerous ways to do this but normally training a simple [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) model will be enough. You can also do topic modelling with TF-IDF vectorization by combining it with LSA. [This](http://text2vec.org/topic_modeling.html) is a good guide comparing the two.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. Your suggestions have helped me a lot!  But I am so confused now and don't know how to start. Can I find ready-made tools directly on the Internet? If not, how should I do or learn the Topic Modelling?  I am a Master in Electrical major and have foundations in Mathematics and Python.

Comment: @peak There are numerous guides to how do LDA topic modelling in python, see one and try to imitate their example with their data and then apply what you've learned to your own data. For libraries, spacy (for text preprocessing) and gensim for your machine learning logic.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds quite tough to handle it. Also it is not a simple task. If I were you, I consider 2 ways to do what you ask.

1. Make your own rule for it

   - If you complete counting the words, then you should match those word to topic. There is no free lunch. Make own your rule for classifying category. e.g. Entertainment has many "TV" and "drama" so If some text has it, then we can guess it belongs to Entertainment.
2. Machine learning.

   - If you can't afford to make rules, let machine do it. But even in this case, you should label the article with your desired class(topics).
   - Unsupervised pre-training(e.g. clustering) can also be used here. but at last, we need supervised data set with topics.
   - You should decide taxonomy of topics.

Welcome to ML world.
Hope it helps to get the right starting point.